# I want to be able to change each picture to appear in the same place on the screen every time i click a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some problems, the plan is when i click a button, the pictures change one bu one to represent a traffic light sequence. So when i run the code i want it to start on red and run through the sequence (British sequence). Although when i do run the code all i get is all the pictures coming up at the same time with no effect coming from the button. if anyone can help to accomplish this then that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Cheers!

Here is my code for HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Traffic Lights</title>
        <link href="flag_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="flagscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="changeLight()">

    <img id="state_1" onclick="changeLight()" src="http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-light-red.jpg">
    <img id="state_2" onclick="changeLight()" src="http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-lights-red-amber.jpg">
    <img id="state_3" onclick="changeLight()" src="http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-lights-green.jpg">
    <img id="state_3" onclick="changeLight()" src="https://assets.digital.cabinet-office.gov.uk/media/559fbe48ed915d1592000048/traffic-light-amber.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.state_1 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.state_2 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.state_3 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.state_4 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var flagSeq = ["state_1","state_2","state_3","state_4"];

var state = 0;

function changeFlag() {
    if (state == 0) {
        document.getElementById("state_1").className = flagSeq[state][0];   
        state++;
    } 
    if else (state == 1) {
        document.getElementById("state_2").className = flagSeq[state][1];
        state++;
    }
    if else (state == 2) {
        document.getElementById("state_3").className = flagSeq[state][2];
        state++;
    }
    if else (state == 3) {
        document.getElementById("state_4").className = flagSeq[state][3];
        state = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `changeLight()` but all I see is a function named `changeFlag()`

Comment: Are you sure you meant to type `if else`, not `else if`? Also, there are two elements with the id of `state_3`, and none with `state_4`.

Comment: @j08691 that was some thing else i intended to do but then edited it it to be traffic lights but just forgot to change some of them, although in my actual code, they are all called flag with the same functions and it does the same thing i mentioned at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KzhzBZXSZUKkeQFkfHxC)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Traffic Lights</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="changeLight()">
    <div id="light-div" class="light light-0" onclick="changeLight()"></div>
  </body>
</html>


.light {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

```
.light-0 {
  background-image: url(http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-light-red.jpg);
}

.light-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-lights-red-amber.jpg);
}

.light-2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-lights-green.jpg);
}

.light-3 {
  background-image: url(http://assets.digital.cabinet-office.gov.uk/media/559fbe48ed915d1592000048/traffic-light-amber.jpg);
}


var lightSeq = ['light-0', 'light-1', 'light-2', 'light-3'];
var state = 0;

function changeLight() {
  state++;
  if (state === lightSeq.length)
    state = 0;

  document.getElementById('light-div').className = 'light ' + lightSeq[state];
}
```

Comment: Sorry jdforsythe, this is very helpful although i am not sure why you have used a <div id> tag for an image. Also could you explain to me the JavaScript part

Comment: I used the `<div>` because it only requires one DOM element instead of 4.  As far as the Javascript - it just iterates your state counter. If the state counter has reached the length of the lightSeq array (4) it resets it back to 0 (because there's no `light-4`). then it changes the class attribute of the div to 'light light-0' or whatever number, which gives it the default styling of the `.light` in the CSS and adds the image from whichever numbered class is added.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my other answer because this is apparently a homework problem. I'll gladly point out what to improve, though, so here's the first paragraph from the answer I posted.

---

There are several issues with your code, to the point where I wonder why you haven't noticed some of them yourself.

- You seem to only want to show one image at a time, but you never actually hide any of them.
- You're giving the images `id` attributes but only use class selectors in your CSS.
- There are two elements with an id of `state_3`.
- `if else` is not valid in JavaScript (the console will be happy to point out a syntax error). You probably meant to write `else if` instead.
- As j08691 pointed out, you define a function `changeFlag` but refer to it as `changeLight` in your HTML.
- Side note: for real-life projects, you'd be better off downloading the images and using those instead of linking to external resources.

---

What I would do is have only one `img` element and use JavaScript to change its `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Really there are a lot of errors in your code both HTML/JS, first hide something then better try to show it-

Still I got something for you, maybe this is what you needed, check the link below-

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#ab').click(function(e){
      //alert(1);
      var a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for(i=1;i<=a.length;i++){
        setTimeout(function(x){
          return (function(){
            $('img#state_'+x).show();  
          });
      }(i),1000*i)
      }
    });
});
```

https://plnkr.co/XGG5PHI6bMP0XJ484rUS?p=preview